# Best location for Javascript files for specific Section/Item

Tags: coldfusion, fw1

I am creating a website that is powered by FW/1. It is already known that each Section/Item combination will potentially need its own JavaScript file. I am considering having all the JS files near their corresponding view files.

`views/#getSection()#/#getItem()#.js`

I don't like that I am now serving up files from what would normally be a hidden directory. What is the best location for Section/Item specific JS files

Comment: It's not a hidden directory; it's public just like everything in your webroot (unless you've got working htaccess/webconfig rules in place). The webroot should contain files that are web accessible, and as few others as possible.

Comment: Unless these JS files are large and in not commonly used places, it's probably simpler and not much overhead to just minify and gzip them into a single file that's used globally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not a big fan of having any framework files in the web root. I typically only have index.cfm and all my other ColdFusion code lives a level up from web root and is all handled via ColdFusion per-application mappings. I also put all my .js, .css and images files in their own directory in  a folder named `assets` in the web root. No reason why you cannot still use the section and action to name your files and include them dynamically.